# How to show list users which have "SELECT" permission on a specific table?

Tags: oracle

I need to grant a user to some tables in a schema on Oracle database, I already created this user before but the database has a lot of tables (over 1000 tables) so that I need a SQL query to show all tables that user can connect.
This user only can use SELECT.

Please help me to solve this issue !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below query. It will show all the tables that the current session user has access to,

```
select * from user_tables;
```

To view all the tables,

```
select * from all_tables;
```

**List all users who have been assigned a particular role**

```
-- Change 'DBA' to the required role
select * from dba_role_privs where granted_role = 'DBA'
```

**List all roles given to a user**

```
-- Change 'PHIL@ to the required user
select * from dba_role_privs where grantee = 'PHIL';
```

**List all privileges given to a user**

```
select
  lpad(' ', 2*level) || granted_role "User, his roles and privileges"
from
  (
  /* THE USERS */
    select 
      null     grantee, 
      username granted_role
    from 
      dba_users
    where
      username like upper('%&enter_username%')
  /* THE ROLES TO ROLES RELATIONS */ 
  union
    select 
      grantee,
      granted_role
    from
      dba_role_privs
  /* THE ROLES TO PRIVILEGE RELATIONS */ 
  union
    select
      grantee,
      privilege
    from
      dba_sys_privs
  )
start with grantee is null
connect by grantee = prior granted_role;
```

Note: Taken from http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/recursively_list_privilege.html

**List which tables a certain role gives SELECT access to?**

```
-- Change 'DBA' to the required role.
select * from role_tab_privs where role='DBA' and privilege = 'SELECT';
```

**List all tables a user can SELECT from?**

```
--Change 'PHIL' to the required user
select * from dba_tab_privs where GRANTEE ='PHIL' and privilege = 'SELECT';
```

**List all users who can SELECT on a particular table (either through being given a relevant role or through a direct grant (ie grant select on atable to joe))? The result of this query should also show through which role the user has this access or whether it was a direct grant.**

```
-- Change 'TABLENAME' below
select Grantee,'Granted Through Role' as Grant_Type, role, table_name
from role_tab_privs rtp, dba_role_privs drp
where rtp.role = drp.granted_role
and table_name = 'TABLENAME' 
union
select Grantee,'Direct Grant' as Grant_type, null as role, table_name
from dba_tab_privs
where table_name = 'TABLENAME' ;
```

[Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/oracle-list-users-with-access-to-certain-tables/14905#14905)

Comment: Hi Nishanthi Grashia,

With this command above, I cannot found the "UserName" column to filter with my specify user.
Did I need to input more parameter ?

Comment: Yeah Hi, Hope my answer helps you!

Comment: @JackVo: Which query are you talking about? What is the username you want?

Comment: Hi Nishanthi Grashia,

I only want to specify a username which was create by the administrator, not the default user.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#15665

Check USER_SYS_PRIVS, USER_TAB_PRIVS, USER_ROLE_PRIVS tables.

Also using this is helpful:-

```
select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME='SAMPLE';
select * from USER_TAB_PRIVS where Grantee = 'SAMPLE';
select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS where USERNAME = 'SAMPLE';
```

Put "user" instead of sample to get info on current logged user. Hope this helps!